# How can I count the # of items in an associated table that meet certain criteria?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using VS2015, MVC5, and EF 4.5.2.
There's a view that displays a paperclip if there are associated documents.  I'd like to show the paperclip only if there are associated documents that are marked as "print_w_cert".
This works if there are ANY associated documents:

```
<td>
    @if (item.workorder_doc.Count > 0)
    {<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span>}
</td>
```

How do I modify this to retrieve only the count of items marked "T" for print_w_cert?
A few different iterations I tried:

```
   @if (item.workorder_doc.Count(print_w_cert == "T"))
   @if (item.workorder_doc.Count(item.print_w_cert == "T"))
   @if (item.workorder_doc.Count(item.workorder_doc.print_w_cert == "T"))
```

TIA, Tracy

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
@if (item.workorder_doc.Where(wd => wd.print_w_cert == "T").Count() > 0)
```

Tracy